# How do I create a LAN connection between computers on internet

Tags: windows-10, vpn, lan, wan

I want to play games with local server like amongus on bluestacks. I have tried making a VPN from control panel and forwarded the ports, but when my friends connect to the internet, their internet no longer works, and they don't see my local hosted game too.

So I want to know how I can connect PCs or even mobile over the internet just like a connection on the same wifi.

Comment: You need a better VPN that Windows offers - one with Split Tunnel capabilities.  There are business VPNs that do this. I use these.  See if Nord or like VPN can do what you need.

Comment: @John why not just add a static route to to get the internet working again?

Comment: Most likely you didn't set up the VPN correctly. You need to describe your setup procedure maybe add some screenshots as well. To know the source you used might be helpfull too.